# Diophantine extended Euclidean for squares

Tags: nt.number-theory

We can utilize extended Euclidean algorithm to solve for integers $x,y$ such that
$$ax+by=c$$
holds where $a,b,c$ are integers wth $\gcd(a,b)|c$.

Is there a way to solve for
$$ax^2+by^2=c$$
holds where $a,b,c$ are integers wth $\gcd(a,b)|c$?

By this I mean is there a $\mathsf{polylog}(|abc|)$ time algorithm?

I am interested in the cases:

1. Assume the factors of $a,b,c$ are provided.
2. Assume the factors of $a,b$ are unknown but $ab|c$.

Comment: As far as I am aware, no efficient algorithm is known already for checking whether a solution *exists* in the case $a=b=1$, other than by factoring $c$.

Comment: ah ok..........

Comment: I don’t know if this would account, but you can take the theta series $\theta(z)= \sum q^{n^2}$, and take $\theta(az) \theta(bz)$ and look at the coefficient of $q^c$ in the Fourier series expansion, if it is non zero, then it would tell that there are solution, although it won’t give an answer. I suppose there should be some quadratic form related answer to this question